# C# System.Object[,]

Tags: c#, excel

I wrote a little C# program that opens up an Excel workbook and a worksheet and iterates over all the cells in a worksheet and prints out the value in each cell.

The problem I am having is the console is printing `System.Object[,]` instead of the actual cell values, it seems as it is an infinite loop.

Does anyone know why it is not printing the actual values?

Here is my program:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using NetOffice.ExcelApi;
using NetOffice.ExcelApi.Enums;
using Excel = NetOffice.ExcelApi.Application;


namespace excelApp
{
    class Program
    {

        Excel excelApplication;
        Workbook workbook;
        Worksheet sheet;


        [STAThreadAttribute]
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.openWorkSheet(@"C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Book1.xlsx", 2);
            p.printValues();
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }


        private void openWorkSheet(string path, int worksheet)
        {

            excelApplication = new Excel
            {
                Visible = true,
                ScreenUpdating = true
            };

            try
            {
                workbook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(path);
                sheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[worksheet];
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File does not exist");
            }
        }



        private void printValues()
        {

                Range range = sheet.Cells[2, 2];
                Range rngLastCell = range.get_End(XlDirection.xlToRight)
                                          .get_End(XlDirection.xlDown);


            // holds the range of cells in the worksheet
            Range tableRange = sheet.Range(range, rngLastCell);

            try
            {

               foreach(var cell in tableRange.Rows)
               {
                   Console.Write(cell.Value.ToString());
               }

            }

            catch(Exception e)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong" + e.StackTrace);

            }

      }
    }
  }
```

Here is the console output:

[image]

Comment: Seems like cell.Value is a multi-dimensional object array.  What is stored in cell.Value in your foreach loop when you run in debugger?

Comment: Looks like you are loop through Row objects and not the cells themselves (even though the variable is called `cell`)

Comment: @xDaevax I actually can't see as the output is `System.Object[,]` but `cell.Value` should hold the actual data in the cell

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is here:

```
foreach(var cell in tableRange.Rows)
{
    Console.Write(cell.Value.ToString());
}
```

This is looping through the *rows* of the range, each of which is a range itself, so the "value" is an array.  The default implementation of `ToString` for an array is to just print the name of the type, which is `System.Object[,]`.

This should work since `Range.Value` will be an array of objects:

```
foreach(object cell in ((object[,])tableRange.Value))
{
    Console.Write(cell.ToString());
}
```

Note that it also saves the overhead of calling `.Value` on each *cell*, which is an expensive operation.  It's much more efficient to get the value of the entire range into an array and loop over *that*.

Comment: that's the danger of `var`. you don't realize the object types don't match with your vision.

Comment: @speising True, although in this case `Value` will be an `object[,]`, so `foreach(object cell in tableRange.Rows)` wouldn't have identified the problem either.  Better to understand what each property is returning rather than relying on return types (especially for Office automation which is COM-based)

Comment: @DStanley with your answer I am getting the following error `foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type object because object does not contain a public definition for GetEnumerator`